# Formatting a date in XSLT

Tags: xml, date, datetime, xslt, formatdatetime

Using `format-date($date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')` outputs a date as `dd/MM/yyyy`.

**Detail**

I'm integrating with a system which uses the below format for dates:

```
<SomeDateElement>
    <DAY>21</DAY>
    <MONTH>06</MONTH>
    <YEAR>2017</YEAR>
</SomeDateElement>
```

To convert these values to valid `xs:date` / `xs:datetime` elements, I've created the below logic in my XSLT:

Template to match any "fake dates":

```
<xsl:template match="//*[./YEAR and ./MONTH and ./DAY]">
    <xsl:call-template name="ConvertFakeDateToXmlDateTime">
        <!-- <xsl:with-param name="format">yyyy-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss</xsl:with-param> -->
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Template to format any "fake date" (separate to the above to allow for easy reuse for those dates for which I wish to specify a different format / caught via other matches).

```
<xsl:template name="ConvertFakeDateToXmlDateTime">
    <xsl:param name="format" select="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="concat(./YEAR/text(),'-',./MONTH/text(),'-',./DAY/text())" /> <!-- as="xs:datetime" -->

    <!-- debugging code-->
    <xsl:element name="{concat('DEBUG_',name(.))}">
        <xsl:attribute name="IAmADate">
            <xsl:value-of select="$date"/> <!-- show our date variable's content -->
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" /> <!-- show the original value -->
    </xsl:element>
    <!-- end debugging code -->

    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:format-date($date, $format)"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Using the above code & sample input I get the following output:

```
<DEBUG_SomeDateElement xmlns="" IAmADate="2017-06-21">
    <DAY>21</DAY>
    <MONTH>06</MONTH>
    <YEAR>2017</YEAR>
</DEBUG_SomeDateElement>
<SomeDateElement xmlns="">21/06/2017</SomeDateElement>
```

**Additional Notes**

I'm performing the transform with Microsoft .Net's `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform`.

My stylesheet includes the attribute/namespace: `xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"`, for the `format-date` function.

**Simple Example**

I also tried to simplify the issue by doing this:

```
<xsl:element name="demo">
    <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:format-date('2017-06-21', 'yyyy-MM-dd')"/>
</xsl:element>
```

and

```
<xsl:element name="demo">
    <xsl:variable name="demoDate" select="2017-06-21" />
    <xsl:value-of select="msxsl:format-date($demoDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')"/>
</xsl:element>
```

- The first example (where date & format are literals) gave `<demo>2017-06-21</demo>`.  ✔
- The second (where date is a variable) gave `<demo>1900-01-01</demo>`.  ✘

As such, I've been unable to reproduce the exact issue I'm seeing above; though I have now discovered a second issue, implying I've misunderstood something about XSLT variables.

Comment: You need to quote the value in your select to make it a string: `<xsl:variable name="demoDate" select="'2017-06-21'" />`. Otherwise the processor reads that as 2017 minus 6 minus 21. Other than your variable issue, I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: The same for `<xsl:param name="format" select="yyyy-MM-dd" />`, I think you want `<xsl:param name="format" select="'yyyy-MM-dd'" />`.

Comment: Ah; that was it; thank-you both!  Please submit as an answer and I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the values in your selects to make them strings:

```
<xsl:variable name="demoDate" select="'2017-06-21'" />
```

and

```
<xsl:param name="format" select="'yyyy-MM-dd'" />
```